# MUI Autocomplete's dropdown incorrect position with dynamic width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm making a MUI autocomplete that will expand its width when user focuses on it.
But I'm experiencing the dropdown is in incorrect position when user focuses on it for the first time.

Before user focus
[image: Before user focus]

First time user focus
[image: After user focus for the first time]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Currently I'm adjusting width with

```
sx={{width:isFocus ? '572px' : '358px'}}
```

isFocus state is updated by
`onFocus` and `onBlur` events.

Comment: How are you adjusting the width right now? Can we see the code for the component?

Comment: what happens if you use the fullWidth property?

Comment: @angelCanales I tested with fullWidth property but dropdown position is still incorrect.

Comment: i suggest looking at https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#main-content yet if you actually want to make it by yourself, seems like you struggle with css positioning, for which, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this by setting the width values of the Popper and Paper components of the autocomplete to the desired width values when autocomplete is focused.